# Triggering GitHub workflow on a different branch

Tags: github, github-actions

Why doesn't "Workflow B" get triggered upon successful completion of "Workflow A" when a new file is pushed to branch_b?

I have three branches in my repository:

- **master** (default branch)
- **branch_a**
- **branch_b**

In the **branch_a** branch, I've set up a workflow file that creates a file named "test2.txt" and then commits and pushes this file to the **branch_b**. Here's a snippet of the workflow file:

```yaml
name: CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - branch_a

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Create and push build branch
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "myemail"
          git config --global user.name "myusername"

          # Create a simple text file
          echo "This is a test file." > test2.txt

          # Commit and push changes to branch_b
          git fetch origin branch_b
          git checkout branch_b # Switch to branch_b
          git add test2.txt
          git commit -m "Add test file"
          git push origin branch_b
```

Additionally, I've created another workflow file on the **branch_b** branch:

```yaml
name: Workflow B

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - branch_b

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2


      - name: Output
        run: echo "Workflow on branch_b triggered"
```

However, despite successfully observing the "test2.txt" file being pushed to **branch_b**, the "Workflow B" doesn't seem to be triggered upon the completion of "Workflow A."

What could be the reasons for "Workflow B" not getting triggered as expected?

Comment: Pushes using the credentials set by default won't trigger other jobs - https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#using-the-github_token-in-a-workflow

Comment: So, I need to use a PAT?